# Add string in html vb

Tags: vb.net, appendchild

I want to put a string on HTML content.I have the next code

```
   <table>
        <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="pem">
        <td>hello</td>
        </tr>

        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="pem">
        <td>hello</td>
        </tr>

        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So if you see, I need to put 2 "tr" to close it.

I think i need to make a for like this:

```
for each node as htmlNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@class,'pem')]")
            //And here i want to make a appendchild to put only the "tr" to open it
            node.appendChild("<tr>")
```

But it doesn't work because I need to make an HTML node or htmlElement

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tags in order to insert html elements in xml.

An example would be:

```
<xml>
    <title>Your HTML title</title>
    <htmlData><![CDATA[<html>
        <head>
            <script/>
        </head>
        <body>
        Your HTML's body
        </body>
        </html>
     ]]>
    </htmlData>
</xml>
```

Comment: I think the OP is working with an HTML document, rather than an XML document.